# How to get SSID and PASSWORD of current connected wi-fi network

Tags: android-studio, passwords, wifimanager, ssid

I am developing a camera application in **Android** for this I need to pair any ipcamera to a WI-FI network. For pairing process I need to scan a QR code which contains SSID and PASSWORD of current connected WI-FI network. I am able to get SSID by means of **WifiManager** but not able to get password.

Any help is useful "Thanks In Advance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Wi-Fi password is kept in system, there is no way to access it without root! Unfortunately, you will have to get the user to input the password manually as you cannot get it from the device.