# Share the information of current wifi on android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, wifi

I am developing an app for Android with Kotlin, and I want to share the information about the current wifi network my phone is connected to; in order to connect another device to it (the information are shared by Bluetooth).

At first, I wanted to get the SSID and Password by `WifiManager` but it looks like the [password is only accessible with root privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590879/how-to-get-ssid-and-password-of-current-connected-wi-fi-network).

So is there a way to share the Wifi info without accessing the password? I'm sure it should be possible because when I configure my weather station with that app, I don't need to enter the password of my network, it does everything automatically (and my phone is not rooted) :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netatmo.netatmo

Also when I configure my Google Home, it's the same process, the information of my network are shared to the device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any app can do the wifi connecting automatically by saving the password somewhere after you enter it once. Also as far as sharing the wifi information to the other device is concerned, why not just share the SSID with the other device and make the user enter the password once and save it again?

Comment: I'd like to make something smooth for the user, to avoid him entering his wifi password again. It's what happens on the Netatmo app. I just run the wizard and it connects my weather station to my network without asking me the wifi password.

Comment: `again` is what I'm not telling you to do. You can do it just once and I am not sure how your mentioned app works but it's just like your phone and the device for which that app is are on the same network, once they are on the same network you don't need to enter the password ofcourse

Comment: @gtxtreme I couldn't find a method that works fine to get the network SSID.
All the methods I have tried was giving me this message `<unknown ssid>`